# How to increment the date selected from the date picker?

Tags: android

Below is my code. What i am trying to achieve here is i am selecting a date from date picker and i am setting that to curretToday. But when i go to next date it's incrementing Today's date rather than incrementing the selected date. I don't know where i am going wrong. Please help me out.

```
    getDate(icount);

    iv_refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            icount = 0;
            getDate(icount);
        }
    });

    rightarrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                getDate(++icount);

        }
    });

    leftarraow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getDate(--icount);
        }
    });



    appTitleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar_app_title_textview);

    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
}
private void getDate(int i) {

    if(new DatePickerFragment(tv_date).datePickerDate == null) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, i);
        currentToday = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        tv_date.setText(currentToday);


    } else {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,i);
        currentToday =new DatePickerFragment(tv_date).datePickerDate;
        tv_date.setText(currentToday);


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this will help you out to get the date incremented

```
public Date getIncrementedDate(Date selectedDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(sdf.parse(selectedDate));
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  // number of days to add
    selectedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());  // selectedDate is now the new date
return selectedDate;
}
```

Comment: I am able to increment the date if it is from getTime() Date. My problem is when i select a date from date picker i can't able to increment the selected date.

Comment: you have to create a method `getIncrementedDate(Date selectedDate)` and write the above logic and modify as per your needs

Comment: please check and let me know

Comment: Nope..Still the same

Comment: If your code is still the same as in question, then it won't work. You will have to pass your datepicker date to your getDate() method and use it to increment instead of using calendar.getInstance().

Comment: Can u post the entire code if possible?                                  Cause i am not getting the things clearly

Answer (score 0):

You can use next code:

```
public Date incrementDay(Date date) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1); 
    return new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
}
```